# ST_Boundary for geography polygon

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, geometry, geography

I'm trying to calculate the intersection point between a segment and the exterior ring of a  polygon. But I'm not sure how to do it correctly when dealing with geography types.

The segment is a line connecting two geographic locations and I specifically know in advance that the start-point coordinates are outside of the polygon and the finish-point coordinates intersect the polygon.

`ST_Intersection` supports both geometry and geography and I already have the polygon as geography

Building the line as geography it's easy as:

```
LINESTRING(start-point, finish-point)'::geography
```

maybe I can even use `ST_Makeline` and cast its result to geography?? (I'm not sure)

But what about the exterior ring of the polygon geography? I was advised to use `ST_Boundary` however `ST_Boundary` only accepts geometry and returns geometry. I am not sure if the output of

```
ST_Boundary(mypolygon::geometry)
```

is actually geographically correct? For example if the polygon has very large edges would they be segmentized (as great-circles) in the output of ST_Boundary? If not (as I suspect) then how can I obtain the correct geography boundary ?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What have you tried so far? what is wrong with the result you have?

Comment: Check what you get by casting geography into geometry, and if segmentation does not happen automatically, use ST_Segmentize first.

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451981/using-postgis-to-calculate-where-lines-intersect-using-geography-objects/452010#452010

Answer (score 0):

Functions on `geometry` do not segmentize their output.  This also applies when using them against `geography` inputs cast to `geometry`.  So [`ST_MakeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_MakeLine.html) and [`ST_Boundary`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Boundary.html) do not automatically segmentize output.

Edge segments of `geography` objects are assume to be great-circle arcs, and functions with variants taking `geography` inputs automatically take this into account. However, as described in [Using PostGIS to calculate where lines intersect using Geography objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451981/using-postgis-to-calculate-where-lines-intersect-using-geography-objects/452010#452010) the internal computation may not be very accurate for geography objects with very long segments.

[`ST_Segmentize`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) is geography-aware, so it can be used to add more vertices to allow line segments to more closely follow great circle arcs.